# How Xcode Convert var names to View Names in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

I would like to know if there is any easy way to do this

Here is the value name   [image]

Here is the View Name  [image]

I want to know how to do this programmatically, is there any easy way? 
Preferably in Swift, obj-C will do too

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean create the link between the storyboard object and the IBOutlet?

Comment: No i mean generate the string name: i write the name of the outlet and in Storyboard you can see the beautiful capital The and add spaces between words

Comment: I imagine there is code in Xcode that simply recognises camelCase and puts a capital for the first letter and a space before every other capital.  It would be reasonably simple to code that

Comment: well my question is if anybody know if there is a easy way, or i need to do it on my own ), how simple is the code that Xcode  uses )

Comment: Why don't you try?  Have a look at then NSString method `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, for those ho will need this information one day:

```
 let string = "theMostInterestingViewOfAllTime"  //Default String    
 var newString = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("([a-z])([A-Z])", withString: "$1 $2", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range:string.rangeOfString(string)) //Here the String will be separated
 newString = newString.capitalizedString //Here it will be capitalized
```

New Range gave me some problems - is there a more elegant way, compared to my version?